# How do I tell tell a child element in React to seek its video element?

Tags: reactjs, imperative-programming, declarative-programming

I have a simple React app with a video player and chart displaying data about the video. Both are in their own components at the top level:

```
class App extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <VideoDisplay .../>
        <MetricsDisplay .../>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Inside `VideoDisplay.js` is a `<video>` element that I want to control, specifically by seeking its play position, which I can do using `videoElement.currentTime=seekToTime`. I want to control this from the `MetricsDisplay` element: if I click on the graph I want the video to seek to the time clicked on. But to do that it seems I have to call a function in `VideoDisplay.js` from `App.js` when it receives the click from `MetricsDisplay.js`. But this is imperative instead of declarative, and indeed I'm having trouble implementing this in React. Is it even possible? How else could I tell the video in an element to seek, triggered by a click from a sibling element?

I have a workaround that I'll post as an answer but I'm very convinced it's pretty sub-optimal from a design perspective, and will cause code maintenance headaches. So what's a better method? What the "React" way to do something like this?

See attached screenshot: when clicking on the graph in the right, the video should seek to the clicked point in time.

[image: Video and metrics screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

So to get around this I can pass in a seek time in the props, and to prevent it from repeatedly seeking I can increment a `seekId` counter. This seems very backwards, both because I'm re-creating imperative logic using the very declarative logic meant to avoid it, and because I'm indicating that the video element has a persistent "property" of the position I want the video to seek to now and the id of the command to do so.

That is, I respond to a click from the `MetricsDisplay` element with this function in `App.js`:

```
class App extends Component {
  ...
  setPlayheadTime(time) {
    this.setState((state, props) => ({seekTo: time, seekId: state.seekId + 1}));
  }
  ...
}
```

I pass both `seekTo` and `seekId` to `VideoDisplay` and handle it in a lifecycle function in `MetricsDisplay.js`:

```
class VideoDisplay extends Component {
  ...
  componentWillUpdate() {
    if (this.props.seekTo && this.props.seekId !== this.seekId) { this.seekTo(this.props.seekTo); }
  }

  seekTo(time) {
    console.log(`(${this.props.seekId}) Seek to ${time}`);
    this.seekId = this.props.seekId;
    document.getElementById("the-video").currentTime = time;
  }
  ...
}
```

This works, but I have to believe this is not the best way to accomplish what in "normal" javascript is a simple callback function. Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Comment: Ehi Andrew, have you found a better solution? This imperative <-> declarative gateway is giving a few headaches also to me!

Comment: @gabry I haven't come back to this but have come to think that [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) are the correct way to handle things like this that frankly do not fit the top-down declarative framework very well.